# Enterprise library logging 5 for Biztalk

Tags: logging, biztalk, enterprise-library

I am new to Enterprise library logging 5. I am trying to implement entlib5 for BizTalk. Can anyone please help me how to do this. There are less resources in internet.

I have installed entlib5 and configured BTSNTSvc64.exe with custom entlib config settings too.

I am getting this error like:

```
 The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. You must configure the container
 to supply this value."
```

with help of this link([Unity: The type LogWriter cannot be constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950547/unity-the-type-logwriter-cannot-be-constructed)), I tried to resolve the error, but AddNewExtention method is not showing up in BizTalk Orchestration Expression box.

Probably I am doing something wrong in adding the entlib config to BTSNTSvc64.exe config. Can anyone suggest me how exactly it should be done?

Comment: **Could anyone recommend any good tool for BizTalk Logging.** 
1. ETW.
2. Enterprise Library Logging.
3. Log4Net.

I dont want to use Diagnostics. I have done analysis on ETW, but as per my req. its not feasible. Since I have many applications, and I want to log separately for every app.
I am in idea to use log4net. As per link OLD link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626548/biztalk-log4net), log4net could create serializable issues.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am deviating you from your current problem, however, I won't recommend to use Enterprise Logging block in BizTalk. The most efficient way of logging in BizTalk is using ETW (Event Trace for Windows) tracing. See more details on [ETW Tracing for BizTalk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asgisv/archive/2010/05/11/best-practices-for-instrumenting-high-performance-biztalk-solutions.aspx). It's simple to use and does not require any configuration, or restart of host instances etc to turn on tracing. You can log realtime to DebugView or a log file as required.

Comment: I have implemented ETW, but as per my requirements I want to log the data to event viewer as well.

Comment: Logging everything to event viewer is not a good idea, however, for errors and warning you can use System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry method to write to EventLogs. You should use Logging block in case you have a requirement to dynamically chang log writer or log locations by configuration. For configuring logging block, use its Configuration tool to avoid any configuration error like you are getting by opening your config file in Enterprise Library Configuration Console

Answer (score 0):

I also do not recommend to use EL with BizTalk. You've got the versioning problem if you start to use ESB Toolkit which has dependency on the old EL version.
But the main reason is ET is not in good support right now. It is abandoned. It is slow and clunky. There are many other alternatives, fast and simple for all EL functionality.

Comment: Hi, Could you recommend any good tool for BizTalk Logging. I am in idea to use log4net. As per link OLD link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626548/biztalk-log4net
), log4net could create serializable issues.